Trying to import tensorflow_text for hours but keep getting the same error
ImportError: cannot import name 'tflite_registrar' from 'tensorflow_text.core.pybinds' (unknown location)
My numpy version: 1.24.3
My tensorflow version:2.16.1 and 2.13.1 both showed the same errors
My tensorflow-text version: 2.13.0
Thank y'all in advance. This error has driven me crazy. :(
I tried unintalling and installing those packages. Try to match the version of tensorflow and tensorflow-text. Tried to look for similar issue in the Github repo.

try to keep same version for both tensorflow and tensorflow-text, if on windows try using version 2.10.0 for both

try to keep same version for both tensorflow and tensorflow-text, if on windows try using version 2.10.0 for both.
After tensorflow-text 2.10.0 no builds are provided on pypi for windows systems, https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.10.0/#files
I have used v2.10.0 successfully on both windows and linux environments.
